# Difference between return ("abcd") and return "abcd"?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with some JavaScript code that has examples that return a string in parens. Is there any difference between this:

```
var x = function() {
  return  "abcd";
}
```

And

```
var x = function() {
  return ("abcd");
}
```

Comment: In almost every programming language from the imperative tradition of FORTRAN, ALGOL, Pascal, C, Java, etc etc etc, parentheses are simply grouping mechanisms that work essentially the exact same way that parentheses work in paper-and-pencil algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to this question the parenthesis do not have a specific meaning as a string is being returned. There is no expression evaluation involved so both the return statements work in the same way. In case we have an expression that needs to be evaluated, the parenthesis will provide a liberty to first evaluate the expression and then return the desired value according to the precedence rules.

Answer (score 8):

**They are the same.**

The parenthesis, i.e. [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), here will just work as higher precedence, so that'll be evaluated first, and then the value will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference, at least in the way it is written.

Consider,

```
var x = 1 + 2;
```

vs

```
var x = (1 + 2);
```

Some prefer writing brackets around return statement but it is optional and often unnecessary. But I would advise stick to your existing code style.

Comment: For down voters, at least add a comment to mention the reason!